# CPLEX deleting constraints

Tags: cplex

I'm calling cplex.addEq(1, x), where x is an IloIntVar, to add 1 == x as a constraint to my model cplex.

My simple question is: how can I remove this at a later point?

I have already tried cplex.delete(x), cplex.remove(x), cplex.delete(e), cplex.remove(e), where e = cplex.addEq(1, x). It's not working.

Working in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use delete.
Let me give you a tiny example:

```
IloCplex myCplex = new IloCplex();
IloNumVar x = myCplex.numVar(0.0, 10);
myCplex.addMinimize(x);
IloRange myConstraint = myCplex.addEq(x,1);
myCplex.add(myConstraint);
if (myCplex.solve()) 
{
  System.out.println("constraint x == 1 is active");
  System.out.println("x = " + myCplex.getValue(x));
}
myCplex.delete(myConstraint);
if (myCplex.solve()) 
{
  System.out.println("constraint x == 1 is deleted");
  System.out.println("x = " + myCplex.getValue(x));
}
```

gives

```
  constraint x == 1 is active
  x = 1.0

  constraint x == 1 is deleted
  x = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply!
It's still not working though, maybe the problem is something else. I get the following warning: "Warning:  No solution found from 2 MIP starts."

What I am trying to implement is a loop that iterates over several possible changes to the model, calculates the gains in target value for each of those changes, and then selects the best change to be actually applied to the model.
So in each iteration I want to delete and add certain constraints that represent the change.

Comment: The resulting problem is that the model becomes unsolvable in the first iteration already. The mentioned warning might give a clue to why.

Comment: Hi, then you should open a new thread with more information. At least I answered you about deleting a constraint.